# Zalenium: Python: Custom Capabilities

Tags: python-3.x, zalenium

I have the below selenium code in python which I'm trying to run on the Zalenium grid. The code works fine and runs on Zalenium grid when I run the code after running the below docker command.

What I would like to know is what are the Custom Capabilities available for Zalenium and how can I set the same in Python. 
For example couple of Custom Capabilities in the below Zalenium documentation image that got referring the link [Zalenium](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/).

[image]

**Docker Command**

> docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -p 5555:5555 -e
>   PULL_SELENIUM_IMAGE=true -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
>   -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start --desiredContainers 2 --maxDockerSeleniumContainers 5

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

class RunChromeTests():

    def testMethod(self):
        # Below capabilities are for Zalenium
        caps = {'browserName': 'chrome',

        }
        # Initiate the driver instance
        driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=f'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
                                  desired_capabilities=caps)

        # Maximize the browser window
        driver.maximize_window()

        # Open the desired URL
        driver.get("http://www.google.com")

        time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

        # Close the browser
        driver.close()

        # Close the webdriver instance
        driver.quit()

ch = RunChromeTests()
ch.testMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just to set the in the `caps` dict you have shown above:

```
caps = {'browserName': 'chrome',
    'zal:name': 'myTestName',
    'zal:build': 'myTestBuild'    
}
```

and so on...